# How are Direct3D and OpenGL instructions handled in a graphics card?

Tags: opengl, graphics, direct3d, gpu

I am trying to understand better how GPUs work, and I am confused about how they handled high level APIs like Direct3D or OpenGL. It is very common to see graphic cards advertising they support Direct3D and OpenGL hardware acceleration. Does this mean that they handle Direct3D and OpenGL instructions directly in hardware?
I haven't been able to find clear evidence to this, or to them being compiled to an assembly representation that the GPU can handle. If there is such a conversion who does that? The software library (Direct3D/OpenGL), the driver or the GPU itself?
On that same line, where is the graphics pipeline defined? in the gpu hardware, the driver, or the software library? This confuses me specially with the idea of programmable pipelines.

Is there a good resource where I can find information about these details?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have asked a very broad and complicated question. Actually, you have asked **several** broad, complicated questions.

The software that has final governance over the operation of any hardware is called the hardware's "driver". Naturally, for graphics hardware, this is called the "graphics driver." Like all drivers, the graphics driver is effectively an installable part of the OS; the OS is what allows the graphics driver to do its job and talk to the hardware. The two work hand in hand.

There are effectively two kinds of D3D or OpenGL (heretofore known as "the API") calls: those that talk to the driver and those that do not. Every call that actually draws something needs to (eventually) talk to the driver, but calls that set up later drawing calls may just store data locally.

When you make a drawing call, the API does some checks to make sure that you as the user have made a valid rendering call. If so, the API has some options as to what to do. It turns out that talking directly to the driver takes a long time, regardless of how many commands you give it when you start talking. Therefore, what often happens is that the API stores your rendering call and returns immediately. Then, possibly in another thread, it may look to see how many rendering calls have been stored. If there are "enough", then it will forward them to the driver. This is called "marshalling".

The driver's job is to take these calls that have been forwarded and convert them into stuff that the GPU will do.

> On that same line, where is the graphics pipeline defined? in the gpu hardware, the driver, or the software library?

That's actually a pretty tricky question these days, and becoming trickier every hardware generation.

In the old days, the construction of the graphics pipeline was rigidly controlled by the GPU hardware. These days, this is less true, though there is some hardware control. On modern hardware (capable of OpenGL 3.0 or Direct3D10 or better), it would be theoretically possible, if you had direct access to the graphics driver, to design an API that used a somewhat altered version of the graphics pipeline. So the APIs dictate much of what the graphics pipeline looks like.

Each stage in the rendering pipeline takes certain values from the precious stage(s) as input and generates some number of values as output. A stage is "programmable" if the mechanism for generating the outputs from the inputs involves executing a user-supplied program, called a "shader". So there is no such thing as a programmable pipeline (yet); just programmable stages of a fixed pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am well aware of how broad my question was... Sorry about that, but thanks for taking the time to give me such a great answer. It clarifies many things. If I got it right, the API validates calls, groups them and eventually calls the driver through a system call sending the accumulated calls. Does this calls that get to the driver look more like assembly, high level direct3d/opengl commands or neither?

Comment: A driver is just a .dll or other form of library the OS loads. It's just regular code, and it gets function calls just like regular code. What the data structures that are passed to the driver look like is implementation dependent (it changes even for drivers on the same OS), and ultimately irrelevant for anyone who isn't actually writing a driver.

Comment: Sorry I'm so late, but a follow up question: How does the API (OpenGL or DirectX) know how to talk to all the different drivers?  There are Nvidia drivers, AMD/ATI drivers, and many versions of each driver?  An application links against a set version of e.g. OpenGL, so if I update my driver how does the old version of OpenGL know how to talk to my driver?  How does the coordination between the driver and OpenGL work?

Comment: [Loading an OpenGL Installable Client Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/loading-an-opengl-installable-client-driver)

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as D3D or OGL instructions. Direct3D or OpenGL will call into the graphics driver and they will perform whatever they need to do to make it happen. This is not *completely* true of shaders, which do have a uniform bytecode at the API (D3D/OGL) level, and in this case, the API provides a compiler, but those are, as far as I know, still transformed in hardware-dependent ways before being executed. Of course, Direct3D and OpenGL also include user-mode components to improve performance or provide a better interface- for example, they will batch calls to the kernel to reduce context switches.

The reality of GPU making is that Microsoft and nVidia/ATi get together and think about what they want and what's feasible to implement, and come up with a group specification, as the reality is that none of this would work if the major hardware and software vendors didn't co-operate. Nobody will buy a GPU that doesn't support DirectX- and nobody will buy Windows where no GPU implements DirectX. Of course, "nobody" is relative- but it would be a huge loss for all concerned, and of course, if you have a game that is built to only the D3D10 API, then the driver supporting D3D10 is a must to run the game- effectively increasing the value of the product by increasing the range of software it can run, which is a selling point. This means that the semantic difference between being defined by the hardware vendor or software vendor is minimal, realistically- especially as the only two real 3D rendering API's on the PC, OpenGL and Direct3D, follow very similar models for the graphical pipeline, as far as I know.

However, with the new programmable GPUs, you could argue that the graphical pipeline doesn't really exist- a DX11 device can be used for any graphics pipeline you can conceive of, if you have the patience to program it.

Ultimately, the GPU is protected by a strong driver-level abstraction. It implements a C-style interface, and whatever's permitted or necessary in that implementation goes. Everything after that is completely implementation-defined.

You could check out the MSDN documentation for *writing* a graphics driver. I've seen it, but don't have a link handy, and it describes the interfaces that you must adhere to and other things.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. Looking at how drivers should be writing should give a very exact answer to all my questions. I will check it out

Answer (score 3):

You already got two very good answers. But maybe the best thing is, reading the actual programming documentation for AMD/ATI's GPUs: http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/pages/default.aspx#open_gpu

Unfortunately NVidia won't publish theirs.